# I need help creating a for loop for document.querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, forms, loops

I need help creating a for loop for document.querySelectorAll(".suit"). I'm trying to create a form where you input the birthday and the output is a total of 365 options. The example output put is in the HTML.

```
    <html>
    <head> 
  <style type="text/css">
 .suit {
    display: none;
 }

 .suit.visible {
display: block;
 }
 </style>
 <script type="text/javascript">


   window.onload = function() {
    var monthSelection = document.querySelector("#month");
    var daySelection = document.querySelector("#day");
    var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit");
    submitButton.onclick = function() {
    document.querySelectorAll(".suit").setAttribute("class", "suit     visible");
       // TODO hide everything else
    }

  }

  </script>

 </head>
  <body>
   Date Of Birth: <br>
<select id="month" name="month">
<option value="na">Month</option>
<option value="1">January</option>
<option value="2">February</option>
<option value="3">March</option>
<option value="4">April</option>
<option value="5">May</option>
<option value="6">June</option>
<option value="7">July</option>
<option value="8">August</option>
<option value="9">September</option>
<option value="10">October</option>
<option value="11">November</option>
<option value="12">December</option>
</select>

<select id="day" name="day">
<option value="na">Day</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
<option value="19">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
<option value="24">24</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="26">26</option>
<option value="27">27</option>
<option value="28">28</option>
<option value="29">29</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
<option value="31">31</option>
</select>

<button id="submit">Submit</button>

<div class="suit" month="8" day="27">Queen of Hearts, 10 of clubs</div>

<!-- TODO content -->
```

Comment: This looks like homework?

Comment: It's actually a major studio project based on something I'm pretty passionate about: Tarot. So while it's 'homework' it's actually something I'm working on through out the semester as a huge project.

Comment: Recommend using `classList` to set classes rather than setting the `class` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`querySelectorAll()` returns an array-like data structure called a [nodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList).  You can iterate it with a `for` loop.

```
submitButton.onclick = function() {
    var items = document.querySelectorAll(".suit");
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
       items[i].className = "suit visible";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You  jfriend0,  this worked...somewhat. But instead of getting the exact date output I wanted I get the whole list of results. I just want one different one for each date combination.

Comment: @LorraineNazaire - If this answers your question, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer.  I don't understand what "whole list of results" means.  Perhaps that should be put into a new question.

Comment: <div class="suit" month="8" day="27">Queen of Hearts, 10 of Clubs <div>

    <div class="suit" month="1" day="1">King of Spades, 5 of Clubs</div>

Comment: jfriend00 That string of HTML are two examples of results. They both show up at the same time  when I click submit.

Comment: @LorraineNazaire - Well your code assigns every single `.suit` object a new `className`.  That's what you coded it to do.  If you have a different objective, please describe that objective in a new question and show what the HTML looks like before and what you want it to look like after.  Folks here can certainly help you, but you have to very clearly describe what you're trying to achieve.  At this point, I'd suggest you start a new question.

Comment: I can't clearly describe it. I have zero experience with Javascript. All I know is that I want to create a form where you enter your birthday and based on that exact birthday you will have a phrase appear. (As listed in my earlier HTML) There are a total of 365 phrases since there are 365 birthdays in a year. I want only the phrase for a particular birthday to show up when I click submit. Ex. If I enter August 27, then click submit, I want the phrase 'Queen of Hearts, 10 of Clubs' to show up only. If I select January 1, then click submit, I want King of Spades, 5of Clubs to how up only.

Comment: @LorraineNazaire - If you post a new question and describe what you want the display to look like after the user selects a month and day form your drop-down lists, then I can help you there.  After posting the new question, add a comment here with a link to the new question so I know where the question is.